# Computer volume drops when USB deviced plugged in

Tags: windows-7, itunes, audio

This is really an odd issue. When I close the laptop (I use it on a docking station; it doesn't leave the docking station when this issue occurs) or when I open iTunes, the volume *output* on the machine drops.

Not the Windows volume bar itself. That stays the same. But the volume output by a program (like Winamp, but its happened with games too, so it's not app specific) drops. Not the volume control on those apps, but the output volume drops.

A quick restart of the quiet app fixes the issue. But it happens *every* time I close the laptop or open iTunes.

This is very odd, and I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: What all cases does this happen in? when you insert USB devices, close the lid, or open iTunes?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Under "Sound" in Control Panel, try the Communications tab.  If it's set to change the volume, Do nothing may fix your problem.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that setting existed. Thanks. It stopped happening on it's own, so I can't confirm this.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this solution worked perfectly. Thanks! +1

Comment: This was exactly it.  What a horrible default setting!

Comment: thanks, first result in google, quick and easy solution. thank you.

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution, I have been annoyed by this forever, never knew there was a solution.

Comment: Just had the same issue.  Superuser rocks.

Comment: But what if I like this feature and don't want to completely disable it, just don't want the volume to change on USB connect/disconnect, but still drop on Skype calls, is that possible?

Comment: Yayyyy Superuser! Yayyyy Alec! Seriously Microsoft, dumb dumb dumb default settings.

Answer (score 2):

The feature that @Alec suggested to disable might be very useful in some situations. When somebody calls you on Skype, for example. Another way to fix the problem without app restart:

1. Right click on Volume button (located somewhere in the right bottom corner of your screen).
2. Click -> Open Volume Mixer.
3. Manually increase the volume for problematic application.